# Insert Image into Post not working in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have using & install Fresh Latest WordPress 3.6. & not using any plugin now.

**When I am insert into post image. so, Image can not insert in post.**

**& also get below error in Firebug. (multiple browser check but same issue.)**

**"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://www.harnishdesign.net/blog/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"**

How to fix? Please let me know.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: When I am go to from admin & Add new post & try insert any image in post so not insert it image in post.

Comment: I have the same issue. For me it actually does work when I click "save"  or "publish" a second time. Haven't found the reason yet, most likely some security thing from my hoster

Answer (score 0):

Try this in an .htaccess in your /blog/wp-admin/. directory

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
   SecFilterEngine Off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do note to *never* put this in your root directory, as it exists for a good reason.

Comment: Here I am not clearly understand. so please any more specification. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you use simple fields plugin, then go to /wp-content/plugins/simple-fields/simple-fields.php on line 1750 and replace

```
parse_str($_POST["_wp_http_referer"], $arr_postinfo);
```

with

```
if (isset($_POST["_wp_http_referer"])) {
  parse_str($_POST["_wp_http_referer"], $arr_postinfo);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think its a bug the cursor is disabled to click, the easy hack is TAB.

Just tab to the Insert button and then Enter.

Comment: No, it's not. It's disabled because the ajax got 403.